# read label movement at Maze c#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, winforms

This is my maze generator -

Maze.cs and Cell.cs: http://pastebin.com/F4DBARr1

frmMaze.cs: http://pastebin.com/uLVVwD37

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
//       MazeSolution.Cell Cells = new MazeSolution.Cell masWall[x][y];

        //capture up arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Up  )
        {
            label1.Top += -2;
            return true;
        }

        //capture down arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            label1.Top += 2;
            return true;
        }
        //capture left arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            label1.Left += -2;
            return true;
        }
        //capture right arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            label1.Left += 2;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    }
```

this is a code with moving label

i have label on it (player)
I would like to create an array Player (x, y) x = y = 0 
this array comparable cell array Cell (i, j)
Further pressed if the arrow on the keyboard is the bottom of the wall if there is no

IF   cell[i, j].Wall[0] = 0 then y + 1
Then Player, will be at (0.1)

it is necessary to remember the values of the array until  - player(max, max)

this probably should be done in a circle

ps I am not good in english

Comment: What is your question? And please copy-paste the relevant parts of your source code into the question.

Comment: Do you really expect strangers to read through 1000+ LOC? Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue and point out clearly what you have tried and where you failed...

Comment: AS far as I can make out you are looking to check for collision with the walls of the maze and move the player if they didn't hit a wall. Also you want to keep track of the player's moves through the maze?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber  i want use array cell(x,y).Wall() from other class, and dont understand how use it properly

Comment: @TroyMac1ure yes!

Comment: Is this someone else's solving code that you are trying to add player movement to? If so you will need to modify it to allow access to cell information.

Comment: @TroyMac1ure yeah its generating maze code from internet((

Comment: The code is quite complicated due to this. You will need to create functions to get cell information or (not recommended method) make the cell variables public.

Comment: @TroyMac1ure yes this was a problem that i did not understand how to get info from cell(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before moving the label1 you should check for a wall collision. Maybe store your position (X,Y) changes into a Point variable then use that to call a bool CheckCollision() function and if no collision has taken place then update your label1 location.

First declare this in your frmMaze class:

```
    Point PlayerPosition;
```

Then use this function for movement:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        //       MazeSolution.Cell Cells = new MazeSolution.Cell masWall[x][y];

        int direction = -1;

        //capture up arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            direction = 0;
        }

        //capture down arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            direction = 2;
        }
        //capture left arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            direction = 1;
        }
        //capture right arrow key
        if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            direction = 3;
        }

        if (direction != -1 && CheckCollision(PlayerPosition, direction))
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case 0:
                    PlayerPosition.Offset(0, -1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    PlayerPosition.Offset(-1, 0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    PlayerPosition.Offset(0, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    PlayerPosition.Offset(1, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        label1.Location = new Point(22 + PlayerPosition.X * Cell.kCellSize, 22 + PlayerPosition.Y * Cell.kCellSize);

        if (direction != -1)
            return true;

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    }

    private bool CheckCollision(Point pos, int direction)
    {            
        Cell c = TheMaze.Cells[pos.X][pos.Y];
        if (c.Walls[direction] == 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

In the Maze.cs file change the cells declaration to be public (around line #35):

```
    public Cell[][] Cells = null;
```

Then you can access each cell by using TheMaze.cells[x,y] (or it may be [y,x]).

Comment: bool CheckCollision(Point p)
      {          return      }
this function?

Comment: Yes. Also to start I change the above code so that the player will move 1 cell at a time instead of 2 pixels.

Comment: yeah  I thought about it

Comment: (CheckCollision(Point.Add(label1.Location, new Size(change)))) - 4 not 3)

Comment: You may wish to make a variable: Point PlayerPosition; that will keep track of which cell the player is in. Then your label1.Location can be updated by multiplying the PlayerPosition by kCellSize.

Comment: ok moving is here, what about bool CheckCollision(Point p) { return what?}

Comment: It will return True if the player hits a wall and False if the player can move to that cell.

Comment: Point PlayerPosition = Point.Empty;
 label1.Location = PlayerPosition * Cell.kCellSize;
?

Comment: public Cell[][] Cells = null;
Then you can access each cell by using TheMaze.cells[x,y] (or it may be [y,x]).


aDDed

Comment: Updated code to allow for player movement. If this answer helped, please give it an up vote.

Comment: added
Variable "PlayerPosition" is declared but never used
Element "PlayerPosition" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Oops nevermind Thank You man!!!! i cant upvote im new in stackoverflow
BUT THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: i have found random bug - when you first time click arrow player jump to new random location (+-5cells from start)

Comment: its appear when i generate new maze in same program

Comment: hmm its posible that label remember  past loacation

Comment: and i need to make  
if () keyUp and playerpos(0,0) than direction none
and  if () keyRight and playerpos(kDimension-1][kDimension-1) than direction none and showmassage YOU WIN!......

bacase this:

Cells[0][0].Walls[0] = 0;
   Cells[kDimension-1][kDimension-1].Walls[3] = 0;